# How to remove tmux hotkeys from showing in awful.hotkeys_popup.show_help?

Tags: awesome-wm

This is an Awesome WM question and not a tmux question.
I have the awful.hotkeys_popup in use in my configuration, however, for as long as I've used it it has always shown hotkeys and hotkey groups for tmux (i.e. tmux:session, tmux:panes). The issue is that I have never installed tmux on my system; I don't use it and don't plan to. I've always ignored these entries in the dialog, but I want to finally fix this.

I've read online [in the docs](https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/libraries/awful.hotkeys_popup.html) that there is a rule for tmux sessions that *"If no rules are provided then tmux hotkeys will be shown always!"*. Is this why tmux shows up all the time?

I'd like to know how to remove the tmux hotkeys from the hotkey_popup widget. Unfortunately, I don't really understand how to do this from reading the docs. If someone could explain to me how to do this I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what the proper way to get rid of that would be, but the improper way would be `mkdir -p ~/.config/awesome/awful/hotkeys_popup/keys && touch ~/.config/awesome/awful/hotkeys_popup/keys/tmux.lua`. Just replace the `awful.hotkeys_popup.keys.tmux` module with an empty file that does nothing.

Also, you could add `awful.hotkeys_popup.keys.tmux.add_rules_for_terminal({ rule = { name = "no window ever has a name like this }})`. That's equally hacky, I guess.

Comment: Sorry for the extremely late response, but adding the empty tmux.lua file did the trick :) I am a happy camper. Thank you!

Comment: And now I have come up with a new hack: Add `package.loaded["awful.hotkeys_popup.keys.tmux"] = {}` to the beginning of your `rc.lua`. That has basically the same effect as the empty file, but might be a bit clearer since it is in `rc.lua` and not somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks! I do like that a bit more.
Now I'm wondering how to make custom hotkeys_popup lua files for specific applications so I can pull up a list of app keybinds that I often forget.

Comment: Sounds like a new SO question. ;-) Answer is: Just look at what the existing files do: https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/tree/master/lib/awful/hotkeys_popup/keys Looks like that magic is `awful.hotkeys_popup.widget.add_hotkeys()` with the right argument.

Answer (score 2):

The more proper way to do this is to comment out the following from your rc.lua

```
-- Enable hotkeys help widget for VIM and other apps
-- when client with a matching name is opened:
require("awful.hotkeys_popup.keys")
```

Its close to the top of the file

Answer (score 0):

A little late but the one of the answers above is correct but 'ugly' and the other answers a different question and could cause confusion, as it gets rid of all program-specific helpers.

The correct way is to do `$ mkdir -p ~/.config/awesome/awful/hotkeys_popup/keys/ && cp /usr/share/awesome/lib/awful/hotkeys_popup/keys/init.lua -d ~/.config/awesome/awful/hotkeys_popup/keys/`.

After that you can edit the ~/.config/awesome/awful/hotkeys_popup/keys/init.lua file and remove the line that calls tmux.lua .

That way you have also created a ~/.config/awesome/awful/hotkeys_popup/keys folder where you can place different key binding helpers if you wish. You can use one of the existing .lua files as a template.

I have tested all of the above if you are wondering and it works as expected.

One further note: If you make a mistake in one of the files in your ~/.config/awesome/awful/ folder you will completely crash awesome (not like when you make a mistake in your rc.lua or theme.lua. You will possibly get a black screen.) If that happens don't panic, just Ctl+Alt+F3 and either open the last file you edited and fix the error or move you whole awful folder to a different location and reboot and fix it when you log back in normally, before moving it back to ~/.config/awesome.